# My label isn't showing up Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
#Making the frame_____________
class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()
#_____________________________
#Making the actual window
    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("Ethics and similar topics quiz")#Title along the top of the window

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        StartButton = Button(self, text="Start Quiz", fg = "Purple",  command=self.showtxt)

        StartButton.config(height = 4 , width = 25)

        StartButton.place(x=815, y=1)#Positions it

    def showtxt(self):
        text1 = Label(self, text= "What is the meaning of the word 'Ethical'?")
        text1.pack
```

There is my code, for some reason when I add anything else past the start button, it doesn't show up on my window. What's the issue?

Comment: `text1.pack` is not the same as `text1.pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text1.pack()` rather than `text1.pack`. See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) for an explanation of the `pack()` function.